# Converting uint64_t to double both up and down

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, rounding, numeric

I seek to convert a uint64_t to double.

The problem is that uint64_t is not neccessarily exactly representable as a double for large uint64_t. So instead I want a range containing lowest and highest doubles surrounding the uint64_t.

So if a cast always rounds down.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<double, double> Intervall(uint64_t n) {
  auto lower = static_cast<double>(n);
  auto upper =
      RoundUpToDouble(n) == lower
          ? lower
          : std::nextafter(lower, std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity());
  return std::make_tuple(lower, upper);
}
```

So the supplied code is wrong if

1. `static_cast` doesn't round downwards
2. Needs `RoundUpToDouble` which I don't know how to implement

What method can I use to get the lower and upper bound?

Comment: Do you just want to set the rounding mode, or do you want an algorithm that works with the default?

Comment: a nothrow algorithm modified by no global state is preferable but setting rounding mode is acceptable as long as it works with multithreading

Comment: The rounding mode is thread-specific, so that answer is trivial.

Comment: I tried setting the rounding. Unfortunately it seems to be implementation dependent which makes it useless. Or am I doing it wrong? https://godbolt.org/z/qxxk2c